# How to reference AngularDart component attributes outside of component scope

Tags: dart, angular-dart

I've been tasked with creating a webapp using AngularDart. I'm new to Dart and therefore AngularDart also, but have worked through the tutorials at https://angulardart.org/tutorial/.

I've read similar SO questions/answers ([How to access a AngularDart components attribute (NgOneWay) outside of the component, eg. on the page it is in?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24504862/how-to-access-a-angulardart-components-attribute-ngoneway-outside-of-the-compo)) but given my limited knowledge I don't fully understand how to implement Brian's suggestion - or if indeed it relates to my question! Am I also right in thinking that Vink's suggestion is now irrelevant as `@Controller`'s are now deprecated?

In short, I'm trying to figure out if the following is in fact achievable:

- create a top-level `<custom-component/>` complete with attributes;
- within `<ng-view/>` - and therefore nested components - access `<custom-component/>`'s attributes. More specifically, bind/listen for changes to these attributes and act accordingly.

For example, given the following

```dart
<body>
    <custom-component att1="val1" att2="val2"></custom-component>
    <ng-view></ng-view>
</body>
```

and on the assumption that `<ng-view/>` renders the following markup

```dart
<div>
    ...
    <other-component att1="{{customComponent.att1}}" att2="{{customComponent.att2}}"></other-component>
    <another-component att1="{{customComponent.att1}}" att2="{{customComponent.att2}}"></another-component>
    ...
</div>
```

is it possible to bind `customComponent.<<attributeName>>` to `<other-component/>` and `<another-component/>`?

Or, as is likely, am I misunderstanding the use of AngularDart's `@Component`/`@Decorator`?

Should the `@att1` and `@att2` attributes be moved from `<custom-component/>` to `<ng-view/>`?

Alternatively, should I look to architect a different solution altogether? My ultimate goal in this instance is to provide the user with `att1`/`att2` select boxes (from yet another component) which in turn determine the rendered content within each of `<other-component/>` and `<another-component/>`.

Any and all suggestions welcome, I won't be offended if you dismiss any/all of the above!!!

My current development environment is as follows:

- Dart SDK version 1.9.0-dev.8.0
- angular 1.0.0

Many thanks, J

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is to move the two components into the content(template) of a wrapper component and bind attributes of both components to fields of the wrapper element.

Usually a better way is to use events like shown in [How to communicate between Angular DART controllers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22151427) or [Angular Dart component events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26175120) (controllers have been merged with components since then)

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. I had read those articles but must not have understood. I'll take another look...

Comment: Just add a comment if you have specific questions.